# static block - not updating in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and the footer is created in a static block.

I made updates however they are not showing on the website.

I think it may have something to do with ***WPBakery*** page builder. I have checked all the settings and everything seems ok. I made one update which was reflected on the my site, however i have made further updates and it just wont refresh on my site.

So far:

- [backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dsIt.png)
- [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvb3I.png)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use any caching plugin?

Comment: Are you using latest WPBakery 5.45? If WPB was bundled with theme, you might be using an old version.

Comment: yep have the latest 5.45 version and don't have a caching plugin installed.